# onchange event on radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onchange

I am trying to achieve something simple. Basically I have 3 radio groups and onchange of either one of those group, I want to get the values of all the radio groups and display on an alert box.

My code is as follows

html

```
<input type="radio" name="ac" value="yes"> YES
<input type="radio" name="ac" value="no"> NO
<br>
<input type="radio" name="tier" value="normal"> normal
<input type="radio" name="tier" value="deluxe"> deluxe
<br>
<input type="radio" name="cap" value="big"> big
<input type="radio" name="cap" value="small"> small
```

js

```
$("input[type=radio]").on("change",function(){
    var ac=$("input[type=radio][name=ac]").val();
    var tier=$("input[type=radio][name=tier]").val();
    var cap=$("input[type=radio][name=cap]").val();

    alert(ac+" "+tier+" "+cap);
});
```

I have a jsfiddle here too https://jsfiddle.net/5fg6by8m/

ON the fiddle, it seems like the event doesn't fire at all, while on my localhost server using mozilla to browse I always get the values of the first items of each group in my alert box (yes normal big). I might be doing some silly mistake. Please help me correct this.

Thanks in advance...

edit
corrected fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/5fg6by8m/4/

Comment: About your jsfiddle, you didn't added jquery to fiddle and you used `capacity` name in jquery code that doesn't exist in html code.

Comment: i changed it now...thanks for ponting it out. I still get incorrect values in alert box

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use below code. you have to use `:checked` psudo selector

```js
$(document).on("change","input[type=radio]",function(){
    var ac=$('[name="ac"]:checked').val();
    var tier= $('[name="tier"]:checked').length>0? $('[name="tier"]:checked').val():"";
    var cap=$('[name="cap"]:checked').length>0 ?$('[name="cap"]:checked').val():"";

    alert(ac+" "+tier+" "+cap);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="ac" value="yes"> YES
<input type="radio" name="ac" value="no"> NO
<br>
<input type="radio" name="tier" value="normal"> normal
<input type="radio" name="tier" value="deluxe"> deluxe
<br>
<input type="radio" name="cap" value="big"> big
<input type="radio" name="cap" value="small"> small
```

Comment: thank you @Haresh Vidja. I can't believe I forgot that.

Comment: waiting for the 4 minute countdown..:-)

Answer (score 1):

refer the working demo, this will help to you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
</head>

<style type="text/css">




</style>


<body>

<div class="main">
 <input type="radio" name="ac" value="yes"> YES
 <input type="radio" name="ac" value="no"> NO
 <br>
 <input type="radio" name="tier" value="normal"> normal
 <input type="radio" name="tier" value="deluxe"> deluxe
 <br>
 <input type="radio" name="cap" value="big"> big
 <input type="radio" name="cap" value="small"> small
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $("div.main input[type=radio]").on('change',function(){
  var thelength = $("div.main input[type=radio]").length;
  //alert(thelength);
  for(var i=0;i<thelength;i++)
  {
   var theValueofCheck = $("div.main input[type=radio]").eq(i).val();
   alert(theValueofCheck);
  }
  
  });
 
         });

</script>




</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't have selected framework in jsfiddle, so please select jquery in jsfiddle then run the code.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Added `:checked` in your `JS` code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type=radio]").on("change",function(){
        var ac=$("input[type=radio][name=ac]:checked").val();
        var tier=$("input[type=radio][name=tier]:checked").val();
        var cap=$("input[type=radio][name=capacity]:checked").val();

        alert(ac+" "+tier+" "+cap);
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5fg6by8m/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
<input type="radio" name="ac" value="yes"> YES
<input type="radio" name="ac" value="no"> NO
<br>
<input type="radio" name="tier" value="normal"> normal
<input type="radio" name="tier" value="deluxe"> deluxe
<br>
<input type="radio" name="cap" value="big"> big
<input type="radio" name="cap" value="small"> small
```

JS:

```
jQuery( function( $ ) {

    function recalc()
  {
    var ac      =   $("input[name=ac]").val();
    var tier    =   $("input[name=tier]").val();
    var cap     =   $("input[name=capacity]").val();
    alert(ac+""+tier+""+cap);
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("input[type=radio]").on("change",function(){
        recalc();
      });
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorter solution, select all checked buttons using `input:checked` and jQuery `.each()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type=radio]").on("change", function() {
    var results = "";

    $("input:checked").each(function(key, val) {
      results += $(val).val() + "<br>";
    });

    $(".results").html(results);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="ac" value="yes"> YES
<input type="radio" name="ac" value="no"> NO
<br>
<input type="radio" name="tier" value="normal"> normal
<input type="radio" name="tier" value="deluxe"> deluxe
<br>
<input type="radio" name="cap" value="big"> big
<input type="radio" name="cap" value="small"> small

<div class="results"></div>
```